# const arguments in std::remove_if

Tags: c++, list, c++11, lambda, stl

I'm going to remove elements from a **list of pairs**. When I'm using a pair like

`std::pair<const int, bool>`

I get the following compilation error:

> In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/utility:70:0,
>
> from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/algorithm:60,
>
> from main.cpp:1:
>
> /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of
>   'std::pair<_T1, _T2>& std::pair<_T1, _T2>::operator=(std::pair<_T1,
>   _T2>&&) [with _T1 = const int; _T2 = bool]':
>
> /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:868:16:   required from
>   '_ForwardIterator std::__remove_if(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator,
>   _Predicate) [with _ForwardIterator = std::_List_iterator > _Predicate =
>   __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred&)> >]'
>
> /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:936:30:   required from
>   '_FIter std::remove_if(_FIter, _FIter, _Predicate) [with _FIter =
>   std::_List_iterator > _Predicate =
>   main()::&)>]'
>
> main.cpp:17:32:   required from here
>
> /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h:319:8: error: assignment
>   of read-only member 'std::pair::first'
>
> first = std::forward(__p.first);

This is the sample code:

```
int main()
{
    int id = 2;

    std::list< std::pair <const int, bool> >  l;
    l.push_back(std::make_pair(3,true));
    l.push_back(std::make_pair(2,false));
    l.push_back(std::make_pair(1,true));

    l.erase(std::remove_if(l.begin(), l.end(), 
        [id](std::pair<const int, bool>& e) -> bool {
        return e.first == id; }));

    for (auto i: l) {
        std::cout << i.first << " " << i.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I know that (please correct me If I am wrong):

1. I will have exactly the same problem as long as there is constness in any element of the list, for example, a `list <const int>` will also return a compilation error.
2. If I remove the const in the first element of the pair the code will work.
3. The more elegant and efficient way to do it is by using the remove_if list method, like this:

   ```
   l.remove_if([id](std::pair<const int, bool>& e) -> bool {
       return e.first == id; });
   ```

but my question is, what are exactly the inner workings of std::remove_if that impose the elements of the container not being *const*?

Comment: `std::remove_if` requires the dereferenced type to be *MoveAssignable*, which `std::pair <const int, bool>` isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the type and iterator requirements of [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), you can see that the implementation must be similar to the following (from the link above):

```
template<class ForwardIt, class UnaryPredicate>
ForwardIt remove_if(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryPredicate p)
{
    first = std::find_if(first, last, p);
    if (first != last)
        for(ForwardIt i = first; ++i != last; )
            if (!p(*i))
                *first++ = std::move(*i);
    return first;
}
```

I.e., the algorithm assumes only that the iterators have forward capabilities, and elements are moveable, and it `move`s elements around. Of course, `move`s can't be done on `const` objects.

Answer (score 5):

The general [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=erase) shuffles item values around to put the logically erased values at the end of the sequence (it's typically used in combination with member function [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=erase) to actually remove the logically erased values). It can't do that shuffling when an item isn't copyable or movable. Instead use [`std::list::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove).